# Obstacles persist in costmap even after they move out

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running hokuyo laser and move_base on a physical robot, and am running rviz to monitor the obstacles. If I introduce an obstacle in front of the robot, costmap_2d sees raw & inflated obstacles, and shows them as coloured cells in rviz. If I move the obstacle away & out of the laser range (say to the left) , the cells corresponding to the obstacle move to the left and stay there (at the left, within the laser range and within the costmap). I would have expected these cells to get cleared of obstacles.

Which parameter am I getting wrong? My costmap_common_params are the same as  [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/1987/move_bases-obstacles-dont-match-laser-scan-output) . I can include more data or screenshots as needed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11039/obstacles-persist-in-costmap-even-after-they-move-out/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-08-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on 2011-08-29**:
It returns max_range readings once obstacles are gone.

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-08-29**:
Does your laser see points behind where the obstacles were previously that it can use to raytrace? Or does your laser return max_range readings for that space once the obstacles are gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It could be your "observation_persistence: 2.0" parameter. If you set that value to zero, the costmap will only account for the most recent observation data.

~ Brian

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2